# Convert base 16 strings to base 2 strings in tsql

Tags: sql, t-sql, binary, type-conversion, hex

I am not particularly good at dealing with databases, but is there a way to represent binary data as a sort of base 2 strings? I use TSQL. Whatever I do I get binary values represented as base 16 strings at best. For example, I have, lets say, `500` in a cell and I want it to be displayed/treated as '0b111110100' rather than '0x01F4'. This

```
 CONVERT(VARCHAR, cast(500 as binary(2)), 1)
```

gives `0x01F4` whereas I would like to get `111110100` or the like.

I didn't find any suitable built-in functions. However, I came across one dreadful and quite complicated procedure to convert base 16 strings into base 2 strings. Also I could think about using nested `replace()` calls on the values to replace `F` with `1111` etc., but it doesn't feel right.

The whole purpose is to find values with at least 4 `1`s in a row in their binary representation. My approach: if I could make them look like '0b111110100', it would be as simple as `LIKE %1111%`. Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: See if this helps. This function will convert to binary string, then you can look for what you want. http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.com/2009/05/converting-decimal-to-hexadecimal-with.html

Comment: thanks! I will look into it. That function looks less intimidating than the ones I have come across earlier.

Comment: you can also refer to this one it's already asked and answered I hope it helps  you :                                                                                                [sql-convert-number-to-string-representation-of-any-base-binary-hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33092823/sql-convert-number-to-string-representation-of-any-base-binary-hexadecimal)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL convert number to string representation of any base (binary, hexadecimal, ..., tricontahexadecimal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33092823/sql-convert-number-to-string-representation-of-any-base-binary-hexadecimal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping in mind my initial goal:

> The whole purpose is to find values with at least 4 1s in a row in their binary representation.

I took another route (without suggested functions) and could come up with this solution - first, I used recursion via [Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) to get the binary representation of needed values like this:

```
with cte as(
    select 1 code, 29/2 n, 29 - 2*(29/2) bit_val
    union all
    select code, n/2, n - 2*(n/2) from cte
    where n > 0
)
select  code, row_number() over(partition by code order by n desc) 
bit_no, bit_val from cte
```

which gave me the binary representation of 29 (for example):

```
-- code is an id of entity where the value I am trying to convert into binary belongs to
---------------------------
| code | bit_no | bit_val |
---------------------------
|  12  |   1    |    1    |
|  12  |   2    |    0    | 
|  12  |   3    |    1    |
|  12  |   4    |    1    |
|  12  |   5    |    1    |
---------------------------
```

Then I just used an aggregate function (SUM) within a 4-rows window:

```
select *, sum(bit_val) over(partition by code order by bit_no 
rows between current row and 3 following) bits_in_a_row from cte1

-------------------------------------------
| code | bit_no | bit_val | bits_in_a_row |
-------------------------------------------
|  12  |   1    |    1    |       3       |
|  12  |   2    |    0    |       3       | 
|  12  |   3    |    1    |       3       |
|  12  |   4    |    1    |       2       |
|  12  |   5    |    1    |       1       |
-------------------------------------------
```

If the sum of cells in 4 consecutive rows is 4 - I got what I was looking for although it is not quite a conversion of base 16 strings to base 2 strings as I initially put it in the caption. The final answer can be achieved taking only identities where `bits_in_a_row` is equal to 4 (or whatever else).