# SQL: bitwise operation

Tags: sql-server, bitwise-operators

Admittedly, I'm a bit ignorant of bitwise and hex etc. It's just not something I've had to deal with very much. So what I'm looking at is a value of `0401` in my database. I know I can concatenate and get `0x0401` easily enough, but I need to be able to get it to binary form: `0000 0001 0000 0100` though I'm having trouble finding any examples that will do what I need.

Comment: Are you converting from VARCHAR or NVARCHAR?

Comment: It exists in the DB as varchar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert base 16 strings to base 2 strings in tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47396711/convert-base-16-strings-to-base-2-strings-in-tsql)

Comment: Blindy - I don't believe that covers my scenario

Comment: You want to convert a string representation of a hex value to a string representation of its binary equivalent?

Comment: I think so. I know that 0x0401 will translate to 0000 0001 0000 0100 (because I received some direction from one of our architects, who doesn't know how to do this in SQL, hence here I am) but I need to be able to perform this operation in SQL.

Comment: 401, either hex or decimal, does not convert to `0000 0001 0000 0100`. Use any online converter and you'll see 0x0401 is `10000000001`

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something you might be able to use - it will convert an integer to its binary equivalent, just cast your string to an int first - or if it's hexadecimal you can use `convert`. You can add spaces where appropriate if you want it in groups of 4 etc. You could create as a function to use in-line:

```
declare @num binary(4) = 0x0401 -- little endian
select @num= Convert(int,Cast(reverse(@num) as binary(4)))

select
    iif(Convert(varchar(16), @num & 32768 ) > 0,'1','0') +
    iif(Convert(varchar(16), @num & 16384 ) > 0,'1','0') +
    iif(Convert(varchar(16), @num & 8192 ) > 0,'1','0') +
    iif(Convert(varchar(16), @num & 4096 ) > 0,'1','0') +
    iif(Convert(varchar(16), @num & 2048 ) > 0,'1','0') +
    iif(Convert(varchar(16), @num & 1024 ) > 0,'1','0') +
    iif(Convert(varchar(16), @num & 512 ) > 0,'1','0') +
    iif(Convert(varchar(16), @num & 256 ) > 0,'1','0') +
    iif(Convert(varchar(16), @num & 128 ) > 0,'1','0') +
    iif(Convert(varchar(16), @num & 64 ) > 0,'1','0') +
    iif(Convert(varchar(16), @num & 32 ) > 0,'1','0') +
    iif(Convert(varchar(16), @num & 16 ) > 0,'1','0') +
    iif(Convert(varchar(16), @num & 8 ) > 0,'1','0') +
    iif(Convert(varchar(16), @num & 4 ) > 0,'1','0') +
    iif(Convert(varchar(16), @num & 2 ) > 0,'1','0') +
    iif(Convert(varchar(16), @num & 1 ) > 0,'1','0')
```

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=78e401937886be88a06bb80c3c27f3bb)

Edit - convert little endian byte order like so:

```
declare @little binary(4) = 0x0401
select Cast(reverse(@little) as binary(4)) bigEndian
```

Comment: After a lot of editing to work in T-SQL, I can confirm this does not work as intended. I get nothing but 1's for all 16 slots.

Comment: @jw11432 it works for me when I tried, what version of sqlserver are you using?

Comment: see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=78e401937886be88a06bb80c3c27f3bb)

Comment: Apologies, I made an assumption that this wouldn't work as is, because to me it looked like SSRS Expression code. Running it as is does appear to work, so that's my bad. Though this conversion does spit out a different end result than I expected (`0000 0001 1001 0001` vs `0000 0001 0000 0100`) I believe this is what I'm looking for

Comment: Your binary value in hex is 104, not 401. The decimal equivalent is 260. In the above code if you use `declare @num int =  Convert(INT, 0x00000104)` you'll get your expected binary value.

Comment: I actually just got back from the architect and he clarified it's stored as little endian, which does greatly affect conversions. Thank you

Comment: @jw11432 Ah ok in which case you'd need to reverse the byte order, you can use `reverse` for that, have edited and added an example - will take your 0401 and convert to 0104 which then gives your expected binary.