# How to convert decimal value to hexadecimal in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

How to convert decimal value to hexadecimal in SQL SERVER.. 
example I have `ID Decimal(20,0) value(141021750051366541)` to convert into hexadecimal something like this `06ca02dc04426208`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL convert number to string representation of any base (binary, hexadecimal, ..., tricontahexadecimal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33092823/sql-convert-number-to-string-representation-of-any-base-binary-hexadecimal)

Answer (score 0):

If your number fits into `bigint`, you can simply `format(cast(@yourNumber as bigint), 'x')`